# Telerik MVC grid footer customization

Tags: footer, telerik-grid, telerik-mvc

I have a footer with column totals on my Telerik MVC grid.   I would like to add some additional calculations.  I have some description note columns that have footers that aren't being used and I would like to add together some of the other subtotals in the footer of this column.

Any ideas on how to do this?  I figure I either have to have access to aggregate functions on other columns or will have to do some sort of ajax / server side coding to get these values out of the database and run some calculation on them.

Steve

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There's a [demo](http://demos.telerik.com/aspnet-mvc/grid/headerfootertemplates) for custom headers and footers that don't require using the built-in aggregates.